# how to make post request by axios with multiple parameters in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

My Springboot backend rest API is expecting a POST request with 2 parameters as follows:-

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/profile" , consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public ResponseEntity<?> addOrUpdateProfile(@RequestPart("profile") Profile profile,  @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println("file name:"+file.getOriginalFilename()+" file is here. Save it");
    profileService.saveOrUpdateExpense(profile);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Expense added succcessfully", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I can test the backend code by curl as:-

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'  -F profile='{ "displayName": "ma ma",  "birthDate": "1999-01-01", "gender": "male"};type=application/json' -F file=@'/home/dev/Downloads/file.pdf;type=application/octet-stream'   http://localhost:8080/profile
```

Now I am trying to make the same POST request by axios in my react frontend. I am new to ReactJs and I couldn't find out how to do it. Plese let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this you can use post of axios with multiple parameter
and set the Content-Type header to multipart/form-data for file

```
  var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", '/home/dev/Downloads/file.pdf');
    formData.append("data", {"displayName": "ma ma",  "birthDate": "1999-01-01", "gender": "male"});
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/profile', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
```

Comment: but I need the file as well in the request. I can do only one param without any problem. You might not notice the ending of the request.  -F file=@'/home/dev/Downloads/file.pdf;type=application/octet-stream'

Comment: When I post I got error code 415. That means unsupported Media Type.